# System.InvalidCastException 'Conversion from string "" to type 'double' is not valid'

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on a project for my college where i have to create a program that can be used on a hand held computer for waiters. I have created another form where the user can enter a table number, however when the text box is empty after being inputted into an error occurs.

> System.InvalidCastException 'Conversion from string "" to type 'double' is not valid'

```
Public Module GlobalVariables
    Public TableNumber As Integer
End Module

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub TableNumber_TableNumber_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TableNumber_TableNumber.TextChanged
        If TableNumber_TableNumber.Text > 25 Then
            TableNumber_Error.Visible = True
            If TableNumber_TableNumber.Text < 1 Then
                TableNumber_Error.Visible = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my first time coding in visual basic, i am confused because i have not cast anything as a double.

Comment: What you need to do is set [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) and let Visual Studio show you the problems and suggest solutions.

Comment: Then decide what you want to happen when there is nothing in the `TableNumber_TableNumber` TextBox. You could use [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) to check if what has been entered could actually be a number, and not something like "Yes".

Comment: I have Option Strict on, it did not suggest anything when i was designing the code.

Comment: If Option Strict was On, it would have shown that there is something wrong with the line `If TableNumber_TableNumber.Text > 25 Then`. To make extra sure, you can type `Option Strict On` as the first line before all the code.

Comment: Of course you **don't** have Option Strict On. `TableNumber_TableNumber.Text > 25` compares a string to a numeric value, you cannot do that with Option Strict On. Also, when you handle the `TextChanged` event, you check if the Text property returns an empty/null string (e.g., `if string.IsNullOrEmpty(TableNumber_TableNumber.Text) then return` or `IsNullOrWhitespace` etc. as a minimal validation)

Comment: The logic seems off, as well.  If it passes the first check of ````> 25```` then it's impossible to then pass the check of ````< 1````.  It sounds like you wanted to use an ````If ElseIf```` -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a similar Sub based on the logic you are executing.  I added some notes next to the code that might help.

```
Private Sub txtTest_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtTest.TextChanged

        ' Make sure textbox isn't empty.  Really you'd have front-end validation to handle this, but never hurts to add server-side
        ' I like to use the 'Me' keyword -- just a habit, but you don't have to use it
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.txtTest.Text) Then

            ' 'R' is used to declare a double
            ' If you want to it be an Integer, then update the code accordingly
            Dim numberToCompare As Double = 0R

            ' trim the text to remove any leading/trailing spaces
            If Not Double.TryParse(Me.txtTest.Text.Trim(), numberToCompare) Then

                ' the conversion failed...user might have entered a letter or symbol
                ' display error message if desired, and exit the sub
                Return
            End If


            ' If we got here, the Parse succeeded
            If numberToCompare > 25.0R Then

                ' execute logic

            ElseIf numberToCompare < 1.0R Then

                ' execute logic
                ' if it passed the first logic check, then it won't execute this ElseIf
            Else

                ' none of the above logic checks were true
                ' execute logic

            End If


        Else
            ' display error message if desired
        End If

    End Sub
```